# Vb.net send message on discord webhook

Tags: vb.net, discord, webhooks

I want to send a message from my Vb.net application to discord server, but i don't know what exactly way to do it, here's my code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using x As New HttpRequest
            x.KeepAlive = True
            x.IgnoreProtocolErrors = True
            x.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.3"
            x.Cookies = New CookieDictionary(False)
            Dim dis As String = x.Post("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/681417452596232216/blahblahblahbsamplesample", String.Concat(New String() {"{""content"":", TextBox1.Text, "}"}), "application/json").ToString()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with servers and links, consider using C#. I couldn't test your code since you haven't specify whether you are using a custom class.

But if you insist using VB.NET to send Discord Web Hooks, i found a precise project for that created in VB.NET. Check it out here: [Discord-Webhook-Announcer](https://github.com/Kowalski7/Discord-Webhook-Announcer/tree/master/Discord%20Webhook%20Announcer)

If you will switch this project to C#, you will have to create a class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SendWebHook_Test
{
    class Http
    {
        public static byte[] Post(string uri, 
NameValuecollection pairs)
        {
            using (webClient= new WebClient())
                return WebClient.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
        }
    }
}
```

We're using the same method WebClient. But in this example, we have 3 **TextBox** controls.

- TextBox1 for the URL specified
- TextBox2 for the display name
- TextBox3 for the Message
- And one Button

On your Main form, a public static void to trigger the WebHook to send itself will be declared.

```
public static void sendWebHook(string URL, string msg, 
string username)
{
    Http.post(URL, new NameValueCollection()
    {
        {
            "username",
            username
        },
        {
            "content",
            msg
        }
    });
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sendWebHook(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text); 
}
```

Hopefully, i have answered your question, i have difficulties testing this with Discord. Forgive me for any flaws.

Comment: This is probably a great answer but the question is tagged vb.net.

Comment: If you are looking for a vb.net version of the project, see at the beginning of my answer i referenced a project called Discord-Webhook-Announcer. Again, try using C#, but all the best.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your answer closely since I am unfamiliar with Discord. I just noticed the C# code. Why do you say that C# is better for servers and links?

Comment: Simply because C# supports and participates in XML-RPC which is a remote procedure protocol. Also i couldn't imagine VB.NET in network programming. But it is possible, see Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/